# NHibernate lazy loading in a read only/warehouse scenario

Tags: sql-server-2008, nhibernate

In SQL Server 2008 R2 given a table structure of three (or more) one to one related tables, for example... (CaseId is the common primary key)

CaseTable:
CaseId
Col1
Col2

CaseDetailTable:
CaseId
Col1
Col2

CaseMoreDetailTable:
CaseId
Col1
Col2

Then put a view over the top of it e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW MyView
    SELECT CaseTable.Col1 AS CaseCol1, CaseDetailTable.Col1 AS CaseDetailCol1,
    CaseMoreDetailTable.Col1 AS CaseMoreDetailCol1
    FROM CaseTable
    INNER JOIN CaseDetailTable
    ON CaseTable.CaseId = CaseDetailtable.CaseId
    INNER JOIN CaseMoredetailTable
    ON CaseTable.caseId = caseMoreDetail.CaseId
```

Now, if I map NHibernate to the view will it be able to lazy load through the view and not, for example select data from CaseMoreDetail if the view were called with...

```
SELECT CaseCol1, CaseDetailCol1
FROM MyView
```

Or, would it better to map the three tables to entities and thus ensure it can lazy load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one to one mapping ***does not supports lazy loading*** AFAIK. The same for the view, if you map the view you stick into the view all the join so there is no way to lazy load the associations. Try to specify the associated parts as `<many-to-one>` association in the main entity.

Comment: You can actually map a one to one relationship as a many to one to achieve lazy loading if you wish.

Comment: @ColeW thanks I actually wrote it in the reply, but forgot to mark as code, so <many-to-one> disappear from the text :)